# I lose 1px with same value of width in %

Tags: html, css

When I put width with % I lose 1px in some value.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cD2Lf/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="div_centent " >
    <div   class="ligne_inscription" >
        <div class="label_inscription">Email :</div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div_centent {
    width: 49%; /***** here the problem *****/
    border: 1px solid #8096c4;
}
.ligne_inscription {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.label_inscription {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

With `width: 49%;` or `width: 52%;`  I lose 1px, with `width: 49%;` and `width: 50%;` or a numerique vaue like `width: 100px;` it's okay.

Can somebody explain why?

P.S I want a explanation not to change the display from table to block because the problem is in the div with `display: table` not in the div where i put `width: 49%;` because with `display: block` it's okey

Comment: percentages are relative to the container width so could you clarify   compared to what you loose that 1px width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a rounding problem/bug with the display:table implementation.

I just looked it up on chrome and while defining width, it doesn't round down the number but when reading it for the child element it does round it down.

You'll see that the parent is 241.5625 pixels
[image: Image for parent]

While the child is 241px.
[image]

Don't know if having the border on the wrapper div is crucial but moving the border to the table one should solve the problem.

Comment: @Youssef  I noticed this problem too  when you resize the page.. sometimes the extra pixel is gone and sometimes it appears again... so it is definitely a rounding bug... however... it might seem like a little bit of a hack, but if you make the table width 101% it looks like it got fixed in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers will not do 50% + 50% = 100% width.

I believe it is because decimal values for pixels are rounded.

Very silly example, but for a 3px box, the browser may determine that the two halves should be 2px each so the total would be 4px.

Comment: but the problem is in the div with `display: table` not in the div where i put `width: 49%;` because with `display: block` it's okey

Comment: True, but that may be one thing that the browser uses to determine what to do about 50%. Not saying it's right, but browsers can do some strange things.

Comment: but the problem i put `with: 100%` in the div with display table and i think the browser must fill all the with but he didn't

Comment: Your accepted answer is exactly what I was trying to describe in mine, but Ege explained it better :)

Comment: soory @Fiona i didn't understand what "rounded" mean ... but in the accepted question with picture i got it.

Comment: Not a problem, I was just trying to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

dellchange

**CSS**

```
.ligne_inscription {
    display: run-in;   /**add**/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: I want a explanation not to change the display from table to block

Comment: if you not change  add this box-sizing: content-box;

Comment: no i try it .. it's not about the box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: add display: table; to .div_centent

Comment: i have a big code and it don't work if i change it like you did ... i have to keep my display like in the question

Comment: try display: run-in; in.ligne_inscription should help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54790/discussion-between-user3661264-and-youssef).